# how to make group of two array with given array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

i have one array and elements like:-

```
enter code here
$array =  array('1', '2', '3', '4','5','6'); // n number of elements
echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); die;
```

when i print this array its give me this result

```
enter code here
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => 4
[4] => 5
[5] => 6
)
```

i want output something like:-

```
enter code here
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 4
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 6
    )
)
```

Can anyone help me how i can make two group of elements 
Not:- array elements are dynamic it may be **n** number of elements

Comment: `array_chunk ($array,2);`

Comment: no i want to do with core coding like in foreach

Comment: what if the number of items is not even?

Comment: then it will show only one item on that array

Comment: Let me know if my solution helped resolve this in the way you wish.  I still would use `array_chunk()` as it is faster, but if you are processing information on the sub-values, you might consider `array_walk`, `array_map` etc.  in combination with Anant's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are requesting an example using `foreach`, you can use the modulus `%` mathematics operator to check every `x`.

```
$array = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 );

$tmp = array();      // temporarily hold values
$newarray = array(); // new array to hold final results

foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    $tmp[] = $value; // add this value to temporary variable
    if (($key + 1) % 2 == 0) {
        $newarray[] = $tmp; // add temporary variable to new array
        $tmp = array(); // reset temporary variable
    }
}


// add remaining from odd number (if any)
if(count($tmp) > 0) {
    $newarray[] = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: @Kiraang thank you works like charm :) one thing more if i want to do 3 elements in group what we do please explain

Comment: @kunal - just change the `if (($key + 1) % 2 == 0)` to `if (($key + 1) % 3 == 0)`  -- essentially, just change the number following the `%` to whatever number you desire.  The catch `if(count($tmp) > 0) { ... }` is to handle any remainder elements (so if the array is not evenly divisible by the count you wish)   -- example, array contains 24 items, and you want 5 in each group.  This catch would grab the last 4 and put them in `$newarray`